# Modifying each word of a function

Tags: javascript, string

What I'm trying to do is write a function that modifies each of the words in a string into piglatin. For each of the words, it needs to change it depending on if it starts witha vowel or not. It needs to add way at the end of each word with a consonant, and each word that starts with a vowel, needs to have ay added to the end. Lastly, for every word, it needs to put the first letter of the word at the end before adding those sufixxes. Any advice?

```
function pigLatin(whatWeTitle) {
            var alertThis = " ";
            var whatWeTitle = document.getElementById("isLeaper").value;
            var splitArray = whatWeTitle.split(" ");
            var finalString = "";
            for ( i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
                finalString += splitArray[i] + "ay ";
            }
            alert(finalString);
        }
```

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track.  Do you have any specific questions?  It looks like a small amount of simple string logic is all you need to add to finish your homework.  Here's a little hint to get you rolling... You can use [String.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to find the first letter of a word.  Please follow the link to read the documentation, which will explain everything.  It also includes helpful examples. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This looked like a bit of fun, here's a function based on [`String.prototype.replace`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11), which can accept a function for the replacement:

```
function textToPig(t) {
  var vowels = {a:'a',e:'e',i:'i',o:'o'};

  return t.replace(/\w+/g, function(s){
    var first = s.substring(0,1);
    var rest = s.substring(1);

    return rest + first + (first in vowels? 'ay' : 'way')

  });
}

textToPig('foo bar each other   ') // "oofway arbway acheay theroay   "
```

Is that what you want? Be careful of hyphenated words.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you for including a link to the spec.  I've never seen that before (which is bad).  Now I've got it bookmarked!